# Should I accept any answer if the question may have more than one answers?

Tags: discussion

Lets say, the question is intended for the curiosity purposes and has (as most of the problems have...) several answers. Should I mark any answer as "Accepted" in that case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Accepting an answer is completely optional. It is simply a social convention to indicate which answer the author found helpful.

If one answer isn't more notable than another, it is okay (and probably logical) NOT to accept an answer. The answers will sort by vote order.